# dealing with Hibernate second level cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redisson

I'm working on Java Spring project where we use Hibernate second level cache, Redisson is our cache region provider, by accessing a cache values by the following:

```
Collection<Object> mylist=redissonClient.getMapCache("regionName").readAllValues();
```

and the output is something like this:

```
[read-write Item(CacheEntry(com.example.test.entities.myEntity))]
```

How can I change the fully qualified class name "com.example.test.entities.myEntity" to be just captured as myEntity.

I need to unify the name because I have different sub-projects accessing the same cache and same classes and the fully qualified name for the same class differs from sub-project to another.

Comment: you can't. HBN uses `org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl#subclass` field to validate consistency.

Comment: You can use the full class name to get the class and on class you can call `.getSimpleName()`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov do you recommend an alternative solution, how can I read cached items without the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity , one solution would be to have a distinct cache region for each sub-project, but that will imply having to write code to evict other regions on cache content update to ensure data consistency.

Comment: The solution is pretty simple: share models across all projects involved.